# Zombicide 2nd Edition: Doug's Matching Set doubt

Tags: zombicide

I played 2nd edition a couple times, both with Doug, and I have a doubt about his "Matching Set" ability. I'm using the italian translated version but, even reading the original english phrasing online, I'm unsure about whether the ability grants **EVERYONE** or **ONLY DOUG** the ability to find another weapon upon searching. The ability is the only one that states "When **A** survivor..." rather than "When **THE** survivor...", making me feel like, when Doug is in play, ANYONE that finds a weapon with the double icon gets another. Still, every post online suggests that it's only Doug that gets to benefit from this ability (which would make sense, to be honest). So, does anyone know which is the correct interpretation of that rule?